# Ubuntu won't boot because of grub

Tags: grub2

A couple of days ago i booted Ubuntu and got a black screen with text saying (grub rescue>) I've tried different tutorials on how to repair/restore grub but i get (error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd1'.) almost every time. Btw I'm now using super grub disk

Answer (score 0):

I got that several times. Every time, I solved it by downloading a system rescue iso file and burning it to a cd or a usb drive. Booting from it instead of the hard drive, there's an option to rebuilt grub.

There are several options out there for these kind of software. You will easily find it.

Comment: OK i'll see if this works